# Algorithm to find all possible results using text search

Tags: algorithm, search, web-crawler

I am currently making a web crawler to crawl all the possible characters on a video game site (Final Fantasy XIV Lodestone).

My interface for doing this is using the site's search. http://lodestone.finalfantasyxiv.com/rc/search/characterForm

If the search finds more than 1000 characters it only returns the first 1000. The text search does not seem to understand either *, ? or _.

If a search for the letter a, I'm getting all the characters that have a in their names rather than all characters that start with a.

I'm guessing I could do searches for all character combination aa, ab, ba, etc. But that doesn't guarantee me:

- I will never get more than 1000 result
- It doesn't seem very efficient has many characters would appear multiple times and would need to be filtered out.

I'm looking for an algorithm on how to construct my search text.

Comment: Just be aware that if they think you're data mining, they may ban your IP http://support.jp.square-enix.com/rule.php?id=902&la=1&tag=useragreement_e http://support.jp.square-enix.com/rule.php?id=902&la=1&tag=playerssite

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I will definitivly contact them. It's a very fun project and so far I have had a blast but I will contact them before continuing.

Comment: Update: After making several attemps at communication by email I have never even received an auto-reply. I have decided to cancel this project because of this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considered as a practical problem, have you asked Square Enix for some kind of API access or database dump? They might prefer this to having you scrape their search results.

Considered purely in the abstract, it's not clear that any search strategy will succeed in finding all the results. For suppose there were a character called "Ar", how would you find it? If you search for "ar", the results only go as far as at Ak—. If you search for "a" or "r", the situation is even worse. Any other search fails to find this character. (In practice you might be able to find "Ar" by guessing its world and/or main skill, but in theory there might be so many characters with that skill on that world that this remains ineffective.)

Comment: I will contact them regarding access and cross my fingers. I was hoping to be able to access all characters with search. Without wildcards or such IDK if it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Main question here is what are you planning to do with all those characters. What is the purpose of your program? Putting that aside, you can search for single letter, and filter by both main skill and world (using double loop). It is highly unlikely that you will ever have more that 1000 hits that way for any consonant. If you want to search for name starting with vowel then use bigraph vowel-other_letter in a loop that iterates other_letter from A to Z.

Additional optimization is to try to guess at what page the list with needed letter will start. If you have total number of pages (TNOP) then your list will start somewhere near page TNOP * LETTER / 27, where LETTER is the order of the letter in the alphabet.

Comment: The purspose of the program is to find all characters. Then redo this at a later date to find which characters have had activity. I could find out the number of active players. The most actives class. See which worlds/skills have had the most activity in the last week, etc.  These results could even be presented on a website.